I'm doing authentication using Google OAuth. How do I fetch the details of the user
I'm using Google Passport to do authentication.
But now I want some few extra details of the user such as profile image and gender.
So how do I fetch the profile image and gender of the user.
Helps are really appriciated.
exports.googlePassport = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/user/google/callback",
        scope: ["profile", "email"]
    }, async (profile) => {
        const newUser = {
            googleId: profile.id,
            firstname: profile.name.givenName,
            lastname: profile.name.familyName,
            email: profile.emails[0].value
        };
    }));
})


Does this answer your question? Passportjs - How do I request a user's image using the Google strategy?

@DarkBee I also want the gender of the user but this question only provides me profile image. So half of my question is solved

And that's why questions should focus on one specific problem. Did you try to log the output you've received to find out if these parameters are available? Quite sure that question will also have been asked before. Did you try to use the search before posting this?

See here

@DarkBee i tried to search and the gender fetching was giving me an error. That's why I posted. As the method which i found can be incorrect

I see no errors posted in your question. You should add all details, attempts and errors (as text) inside your question - [ask] - How to create a [mre]

Profile Image can be fetched but the gender can only be fetched if the user has given the permission in his google profile that gender can be accessed by everyone.
exports.googlePassport = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/user/google/callback",
    scope: ["profile", "email"]
}, async (profile) => {
    const newUser = {
        googleId: profile.id,
        firstname: profile.name.givenName,
        lastname: profile.name.familyName,
        email: profile.emails[0].value,
        profileImage: profile.photos[0].value,
        gender: profile.gender
    };
}));

})

You can access user as:
const userInfo = req.user?._json
